# Sending email through Gmail marked as phishing

Tags: c#, email, gmail

I'm sending emails through C# code using Gmail's SMTP server, and on the receiving end Gmail reports:

**This message may not have been sent by: *address*@gmail.com  Learn more  Report phishing**.

The *from* address I'm using is a gmail.com address.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class Email
{
    public string FromAddress { get; set; }
    public string ToAddress { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Password { private get; set; }

    public void Send()
    {
        using (var message = new MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress) { IsBodyHtml = true, Subject = Subject, Body = Content })
        {
            GetSmptClient(FromAddress, Password).Send(message);
        }
    }

    static SmtpClient GetSmptClient(string userName, string password)
    {
        return new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password)
        };
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `FromAddress` the same as the one you're authenticating as?

Comment: Yes, the `SmtpClient.Credentials` property is initialised with the same `FromAddress` as the `MailMessage` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is an auth code of some type that you can set in account settings of Google apps mail, this may help

Comment: This is just a regular Gmail address, not through Google Apps. Not sure if there's some other code in Gmail, but in case you were thinking of it I'm not using 2-factor authentication.